# How to expand and collapse a responsive mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have created a responsive menu, all that is left is to make it toggle. I am unsure as how to show the menu when the word menu is pressed. By default the menu is collapsed, then when the menu button is pressed it expands and when the button is pressed again it collapases.

Could someone please help me out as I am new and unsure about this. I have uploaded my project onto jsfiddle. `link`
http://jsfiddle.net/bLbdavqu/2/
HTML:

```
<div id="nav"><!--nav-->
    <div id="pull">
        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>  
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#.html">About Gnosis</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#.html">What is Gnosis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#.html">Origins of Gnosis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#.html">Foundations</a></li>
            </ul>      
        </li>
        <li><a href="#.html">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#.html">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#.html">Centres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#.html">International</a></li>
   </ul>
</div><!--/nav-->
```

CSS:

```
 body {
     background:brown;
 }

#pull {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}

#pull img {
    float:right;
}


#nav{
    float:left;
    height:155px;
    width:63%; 
    background:url(../images/top-banner.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#nav ul {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    *zoom:1;
}

#nav ul li {
    float:left;
    padding-left:20px;
    position:relative;
}

#nav ul li a {
    font-family:Trajan-Pro;
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#d2aa76;
    border-bottom:2px solid #d2aa76;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

#nav ul li:hover > a {
    color:#d2aa76;
    border-bottom:2px solid #d2aa76;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}


/*1st level sub-menu */
#nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}

    #nav ul li:hover > ul {
        height:auto;
        width:180px;
        display:block;
    }

    #nav ul ul li:hover > a {
    color:#d2aa76;
    border-bottom:none;
}

#nav ul ul {
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    padding-top:15px;
}

    #nav ul ul li {
        float:none;
        position:relative;
        padding:7px 0px;
        border-top:1px solid #000;

        background: #423d33;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #423d33 0%, #4a4843 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #423d33 0%, #4a4843 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #423d33 0%,#4a4843 40%);

        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 14px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow:0px 5px 14px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        box-shadow:0px 5px 14px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);

        transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.175,0.885,0.32,1.275) 0;

    }
        #nav ul ul li a {
            font-size:0.8em;
            padding-left:15px;
        }

        #nav ul ul li a:hover {
            border-bottom:none;

        }

@media screen and (max-width: 1900px) {
    #logo {
        height:95px;
        width:100%;
        background:none;
    }

    #logo h1 {
        top:0;
        margin:0;
        padding-top:10px;
    }

    #header-container {
        height:auto;
    }

    #pull {
        display:block;
    }

    #nav {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        background:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        clear:both;
    }

    #nav ul {
        height:100%;
        position:static;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display:block;
    }

     #nav ul > li {
        float: none;
    }

    #nav ul li {
        padding-left:0px;
    }

    #nav ul li a {
        display:block;
        padding: 9px 9px;
        position: relative;
        z-index:100;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
        position:relative;
         top:0;
         bottom:0;
         margin:0;
         padding:0;

    }
            #nav ul li:hover > ul {
            height:auto;
            width:100%;

        }

    #nav ul ul li   {
        border-top:none;
        background: #615f5b;
        -webkit-box-shadow:none;
        -moz-box-shadow:none;
        box-shadow:none;
    }

    #nav ul ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding-left:30px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
    }

   #nav ul > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }
 }
```

Comment: id should be unique, you have given two places pull <div id="pull"> and <a href="#" id="pull">

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to change the attribute:
I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLbdavqu/3/

```
function show(){
    var show = document.getElementById('the_menu');
    show.setAttribute('style','display:inline');
}
```

You can wrap it inside a div to make it easier and then change the display from none to inline. Question: do you want to give users the change to hide the menu when they click again on menu?
Or, if you are ready to use jquery, just use toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function () {    
$("#toggle").toggle();
});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLbdavqu/5/

Comment: i wish to have the menu hidden as default and then when clicked it expands and when it is clicked again it collapses.

Comment: @JosephHenriquez You just have to add `#toggle{display:none;}` in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="nav"><!--nav-->
        <div id="pull">
            <a href="#" id="pulls" onclick="show(1)">Menu</a>  
        </div><br/><br/>
        <div id="the_menu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#.html">About Gnosis</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#.html">What is Gnosis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Origins of Gnosis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Foundations</a></li>
                </ul>      
            </li>
            <li><a href="#.html">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.html">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.html">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.html">Centres</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.html">International</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--/nav-->
    </div>
```

Script

```
    <script>
    function show(ValueToggle){
        if(ValueToggle==1){
          $('#the_menu').show();
          $('#pulls').attr('onClick','show(0)');
        } else {
          $('#the_menu').hide();
          $('#pulls').attr('onClick','show(1)');
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it hidden as default, without affecting the non-mobile navigation?

Comment: yes you have to give  style="display:none" in inline. what is non-mobile navigation?

Comment: the desktop version of the navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to toggle Menu http://jsfiddle.net/bLbdavqu/8/

> Just Change the CSS of the ul.

Hide List- `$( "#mylist" ).css("display","none");`

Show List-  `$( "#mylist" ).css("display","block");`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show the menu items("Home","About Gnosis",etc) on click of link "menu" and
again hide these items on click of link "menu" . I made a jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/kL1dgvmr/6/

```
<div id="nav"><!--nav-->
<div id="pull">
    <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>  
</div>
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#.html">About Gnosis</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#.html">What is Gnosis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.html">Origins of Gnosis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#.html">Foundations</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </li>
    <li><a href="#.html">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#.html">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#.html">Centres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#.html">International</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div><!--/nav-->
```

Script :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$("#pull").on('click',function () {
$("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2").toggle();
});   
});
```

In CSS you just need to remove "float:left;" from "#pull" .

Hope this would help to you  !!

Comment: how can I have the mobile menu hidden as default? without affecting the desktop version of the navigation.

Comment: Can you explain , by 'hidden' what do you mean ?  Do you want the menu items shouldn't be visible at first and it should be visible only after someone clicks ? Or you want any customized icon like Bootstrap provides for toggling menu items ? Please explain :))

Comment: As mobiles are of 900px and less , you can add class "visible-md and visible-lg" in div having id "bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" . Hope this would help !!

Comment: sorry about the vague description. I want the menu items to be invisible at first and then visible when one clicks on it. The only point of consideration though is that there is a desktop version of the menu that is layout differently. So I would want this to be visible all the time and not be affected by coding that applies to the mobile menu.

Comment: If you are working with Bootstrap , then the classes above i said would work without affecting the desktop region . Those classes are only meant for devices that are larger than mobiles . Using these classes would show you the menu items on screens larger than mobile ones . For mobiles , you won't see these menu items .And if you want your menu items to be visible all the time after first click in desktop region , then instead of toggle() use show() . Kindly tell if my answer doesn't help . Don't feel sorry buddy for anything ;) :)

Comment: if these classes don't help , then use "hidden-xs and hidden-sm" .

Comment: sorry, I am quite new to this so I am unsure exactly what you are referring to. Do you think you could show me in jsfiddle?

Comment: Okay , But before that you need to have bootstrap reference to your code . Unless it won't work .

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution please see the code at

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').hide();$('#pull').click(function () {$("#test").toggle();});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLbdavqu/12/

the updation of your requirements.

Comment: add id to your ul as #test and then apply the jquery methods that are defined. mean while i am sending you another link.

Comment: it also hides the normal desktop navigation. Is there a way to show the desktop navigation by default, whilst hiding the mobile menu as default?

Comment: try media query to get device and then apply different navigations http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/